# What precautions should I take before I let client add javascript to a webpage?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

**Question: What precautions should I take when I let clients add custom JS scripts to their pages?**

IF you want more details:

I am working on a custom CMS like project for a company, The CMS has number of "groups" that each subscriber "owns" where they do their own thing.

The new requirements is that some groups want to add google analytics to see how they are doing. So I naturally added a column in the table and made code adjustements so if there is some data in that column, I just use the following line in master page to set the script out:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "CustomJs", CustomJs, true);
```

It works just fine, only, It got me thinking...

It's really easy for someone with good knowledge of how to access cookies etc from from `js`. Sure, each group is moderated and only super admin can add this javascript, sure, they wouldn't be silly enough to hack their own group. *Each group has their own code so its not possible to hack other groups* **BUT STILL**

I am not really comfortable in letting user's add their own javascript codes.
I could monitor each group myself, but the groups are growing really quick and I will hit a time when I will no longer be able to do that.

So, to brief it up: What precautions should I take to avoid any mishaps ?

ps: did try to google, no convincing answers anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of allowing the users to add their own Javascript files, and given that the only requirement here is for google analytics, why not just let them put their analytics ID into the CMS and if it's present, output the relevant Google Analytics code?

This way you fulfill the users requirement and also avoid the need to protect against malicious scripting.

Comment: Was going to say this. And almost universally, this is the way Google does it on its own user-editable content, if you've ever used Google Code, Chrome Web Store, etc. The regex for a Google Analytics ID is very simple, too.

Comment: This is a very good idea.. Though the requirements **for now** is just analytics, may be in the future it will change to include their own custom scripts, like, I dont know, some widget or site counter etc.. But, do you think its best to deal with that when the scenario arises?

Comment: Yes. Deal with the problems that you currently have to solve. Concerning yourself with problems that may or may not arrise is a sure way to slow down development.

Comment: That's not a very good idea. That's like saying, concentrate on looking downwards while walking, its what you have to deal with, this works well until you hit a wall.

Comment: It's good to be aware of what might be coming up however one of the biggest slowdowns in the development world is over development. We don't need to cater for every possibility in every context. What we need to do is provide value for people. Too many projects are scrapped because they're taking too long or because the scope just got out of hand. Focus on providing value before all else and find the balance between that value and the features you're going to impliment.

Answer (score 3):

Letting users use Javascript is in general, a very bad idea. Don't do it unless you have to.

I once I had a problem where I need to let clients use Javascript, but, the clients weren't necessarily trusted, so, I modified cofeescript so that only a small subset was compilable to javascript, and it worked pretty well. This may be waaaay too overkill for you.

You should not let your users access cookies, that's always a pain. Also, no localStorage or webSQL if you're one of the HTML5 people, and, no document.write() because that's another form of `eval` as JSLint tells you.

And, the problem with letting people have javascript is that even if you believe you have trusted users, someone may get a password, and you don't want that person to get access to all the other accounts in the group.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought about the passwords, its more than likely that the passwords might be misplaced as many groups are a charity groups for elderly people and we all know how they write down their password (no, we have had people call us after they misplaced their password sheet; for reset)

Comment: If you have unprotected javascript, an untrusted user can steal cookies. It would be XSS heaven.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically recognizing whether some JavaScript code is malicious or sandboxing it is close to impossible. If you don't want to allow hacking your site you are left with only few options:

1. Don't allow users to add JavaScript at all.
2. Only allow predefined JavaScript code, e.g. for Google Analytics.
3. Have all custom JavaScript inspected by a human before it is allowed to display on the site. Never trust scripts loaded from third party sites - these can change from one day to another and turn malicious.

Comment: General advise, thanks; but right now we have about 60 groups, and with the new marketing team, we are expecting to hit 1000 by next year (Apr) Then it would be disastrous to (1) let users add js (2) manually maintain every group.. solution?

Comment: @iamserious: Solution 2 then, allow them to select predefined JavaScript code only.

Comment: How would you do that Wladimir?

Comment: @Dhaivat: Jamie Dixon already explained that for Google Analytics, no point repeating it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other choice, you may consider separating path/domain of user javascripts (and cookies).

For example your user have page:
user1.server.com
and you keep user pages at
user1.server.com

So, if you set session cookies to the user1.server.com, it'll render them unobtainable for user scripts from other domains (e.g. user2.server.com).

Another option may be executing all user's javascript at server JS engine (thus controlling all it's I/O and limiting access to browser resources).

There is no simple and easy solution anyway, so better consider using options from other answers (e.g. predifined script API, human inspection).

Comment: Hi, we do infact have ``group1.domain.com``, ``group2.domain.com`` etc I am not terribly concerned of cross group hack (as its almost impossible with just js) but just the same, someone can decide to be a "wise ass" and try to steal their group user's cookies. My session is on the server and Its again impossible to get password, but having the cookie, they can hijack session and use it temporarily.